# Map an array without losing unchanged elements

Tags: arrays, ruby

I split the following string:

```
str = "0001110010101000011111100001110010000010000000011101011100001"
```

into an array of grouped `"0"`s and `"1"`s:

```
str_arr = []
str.scan(/((.)\2*)/) { |x| str_arr.push(x[0]) }

str_arr # => ["000", "111", "00", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0000", "111111", "0000", "111", "00", "1", "00000", "1", "00000000", "111", "0", "1", "0", "111", "0000", "1"]
```

I want to replace elements which contain the character `"1"` and have a `length` of less than 3 characters with the character `"."`, but retain the other elements.

I reached this far in my code:

```
str_arr.map!{|x| if x.include?("1") && x.length < 3; x = "." end}

str_arr # => [nil, nil, nil, ".", nil, ".", nil, ".", nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, ".", nil, ".", nil, nil, nil, ".", nil, nil, nil, "."]
```

The last step is where I trip up. I converted the elements I wanted to to `"."`, but converted the remaining elements to `nil`.

Is there a way to replace the elements I want to change without affecting the remaining elements?

Comment: Please write what you are trying to do before writing your attempt. It is mixed up.

Comment: Do not use words like "in this case", "in other examples". It is confusing. Which case are you asking about?

Comment: Should I have said "in this example". Preceding that statement I said what I was trying to achieve generally and then made it more specific so you knew what I was trying to do in the code. I thought it was pretty clear! If there was a better way of explaining it please tell me so I don't have someone downvoting every question I put up in the future.

Comment: If I knew what you were trying to express, then I would have edited your question, but I have no idea, so I can't.

Comment: Who accepted @smartrahat's edit? It is completely wrong.

Comment: Is that any better? Want to make sure I get this right.

Comment: Have you realized that @smartrahat messed up your question? Besides the code format, your result showing `str_arr` has been turned into an assignment. You better fix that too. Other than that, it became better.

Comment: Okay, I'm new to this and dyslexic so the way I structure my sentences explaining things can be very "interesting", I'm guessing this will be a rocky road for me but I want to be contributing to the Stack Overflow community not confusing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason they are getting converted is because `if` statements in ruby return `nil` if the condition wasn't met:

```
if false; end # => nil
```

To fix this, just use the ternary operator (`?:`) in place of `if then end` and provide the original value as alternative:

```
str_arr.map!{ |x| x.include?('1') && x.length < 3 ? '.' : x }
```

---

**Bonus**:

A simpler regex, which will do the same:

```
0+|1+
```

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't even think to put it to return the element itself at the end of the ternary operator. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Using `each_index` would be appropriate in this case.

```
str_arr.each_index{|i| str_arr[i] = "." if str_arr[i] =~ /\A1{,2}\z/}
# => ["000", "111", "00", ".", "0", ".", "0", ".", "0000", "111111", "0000", "111",
#    "00", ".", "00000", ".", "00000000", "111", "0", ".", "0", "111", "0000", "."]
```